# Thunderbird showing different from name than that in View Source

Tags: thunderbird

I was doing some testing with a website and sending test emails to myself and I noticed that the `From Name` that I was setting was different than that that was displayed in the `From` field in Thunderbird.

I checked the source and the correct from name was visible there, so not sure what's up here!?

The only thing I can think of is Thunderbird does some kind of caching of the From Name when it comes from the same email it has received before? As I'm pretty sure the from name it displayed has been associated with the email address it came from.

Why is Thunderbird doing this and can you stop it from doing it?

Comment: Can you give a step by step explanation of your test process?

Comment: @James It's basically just from a website I have been developing where the user signs up and then it sends an activation email via the PHP `SwiftMailer` mailing library. But, as I said, the Source view in `Thunderbird` is correct, just not the displayed From name in the default view.

Comment: If the email belongs to someone in your address book then the relevant display name will be used regardless of what is in the email headers. Have you checked your Thunderbird address book to see if the address is in there? I think it may get added automatically.

Comment: @James Ok, I found the address in my address book. You may as well post your comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the email belongs to someone in Thunderbird's address book then the relevant contact's display name will be used regardless of what is in the email headers. I think your own address may get added automatically.

If the email address is in your address book then it will normally show with a star next to it, see screenshot below:

[image]